# Enumerate SQL Server services with two different versions of SQL Server present on server

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I'm attempting to gather information about the SQL Server services on remote computers, using SMO thru a Powershell script.  My code seems to work fine with multiple instances present on the server when they are the same SQL Server version.

My problem is that when there are two instances installed that are different versions of SQL Server, only one set of services are present in the ManagedComputer object I'm creating.

Specifically, I have an EXPRESS install of SQL Server 2008 R2, as a named instance called 'SQLEXPRESS'.  The default instance of SQL Server is 2012.  The below code gives the below output, which is missing the 2012 services:

```
PS C:\od\scripts\Powershell\ServerInventory> [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement")

PS C:\od\scripts\Powershell\ServerInventory> $s = New-Object -typeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer myComputer

PS C:\od\scripts\Powershell\ServerInventory> $s.services.name
MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS
SQLBrowser

PS C:\od\scripts\Powershell\ServerInventory> $s


ConnectionSettings : Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.WmiConnectionInfo
Services           : {MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS, SQLAgent$SQLEXPRESS, SQLBrowser}
ClientProtocols    : {}
ServerInstances    : {MSSQLSERVER, SQLEXPRESS}
ServerAliases      : {}
Urn                : ManagedComputer[@Name='myComputer']
Name               : myComputer
Properties         : {}
UserData           : 
State              : Existing
```

For the ManagedComputer object, I don't see the ability to pass it anything other than the computer name I'm running on, nothing specific to a SQL Server instance.

I'm looking for a way to gather information about both instance's services.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  What is `myComputer` ? It's not a valid name or a variable. Is `myComputer` the actual name of your machine? Perhaps you are connecting to the wrong machine. Try with `.` instead of `myComputer`

Comment: Yeah, `myComputer` is the computer name, I changed it from the actual computer name.  I tried connecting remotely and on the machine itself to no avail, using both the name and `.`

Comment: @Panagiotis do you have a server with two different versions of SQL Server running?

Comment: Yes. 2014 and 2016, with SSIS, SSAS, Reporting services for both running side-by-side. All of them appear correctly. Are the services down perhaps? Can you see them in the "Services" applet?

Comment: The services for the 2008 R2 instance are actually off and disabled along with the Browser service.  They are still the only ones showing up in the ManagedComputer object.  The 2012 services are up and running.  All services show up correctly using services.msc and the SQL Server Configuration Manager.  I've attempted with the services (including the Browser) on and off, same result.

Answer (score 0):

To search network for SQL Server instances I use this script:

```
clear
#get all servers with SQL Server
$servers = [System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources() 
#loop through them and get properties
ForEach ($comp in $servers) { 
    $machine = $comp.ServerName

    try {
        Get-WmiObject win32_Service -Computer $machine |
            where {$_.DisplayName -match "SQL Server \("} | 
            select SystemName, DisplayName, Name, State, Status, StartMode, StartName, Caption

    } catch {
        Write-Host("Error retrieving data from $machine")
    }
}
```

Output like:

```
SystemName  : MACHINENAME
DisplayName : SQL Server (INSTANCE1)
Name        : MSSQL$INSTANCE1
State       : Running
Status      : OK
StartMode   : Auto
StartName   : WORK\USSR$DBEngine
Caption     : SQL Server (INSTANCE1)

SystemName  : MACHINENAME
DisplayName : SQL Server (INSTANCE2)
Name        : MSSQL$INSTANCE2
State       : Running
Status      : OK
StartMode   : Auto
StartName   : WORK\USSR$DBEngine
Caption     : SQL Server (INSTANCE2)

Error retrieving data from NextMachineName
..etc
```

As you can see on `MACHINENAME` there is 2 instances running. We don't have any servers with 2 different versions of SQL Server, so I can not check this issue.

Comment: This is an easy workaround, to be sure.  But I'd hoped to use the ManagedComputer class as it gives the services I'm looking for without having to check the display name.

Comment: And we got `SQL Server WMI provider is not available on XXXX` when using `ManagedComputer` class :| Well, good luck finding the answer!

Comment: Apparently there's a bug on that one, too: [link]https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1070235/sql-2014-smo-cant-query-sql-2012-instances-sql-server-wmi-provider-is-not-available[link].  Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Thanks for the link!